# In which step I get charged for reads in the following example?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The following code as an example, I am confused about after which numbered line I will be charged for reads in the query result.

I do I understand the info mentioned in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50888511/4538920), I feel lost in something and I would appreciate some guidance in this.

```
docRef
  .collection('comments')
  .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
  .get() // #1 <---------
  .then(querySnapshot => { // #2 <---------

    const commentCount = querySnapshot.size // #3 <---------

    const recentComments = []

    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => { // #4 <---------
      recentComments.push( doc.data() )
    });

    recentComments.splice(5)

    const lastActivity = recentComments[0].createdAt

    const data = { commentCount, recentComments, lastActivity }

    return docRef.update(data)
    })

  .catch(err => console.log(err) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client retrieves the documents when you call `get()`, so that is when you'll be charged for the documents read and the bandwidth used.