# Firestore database increase read operation when i update a document which i have already have it?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use getDocData function for get one document.

```
 Future getDocData(String docPath) async {
    try {
      print(docPath);
      final response = await fireStore.doc(docPath).get();
      return response.data();
    } catch (e) {
      throw UnimplementedError(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

After i got document i updated same document with updateDocument function.

```
 Future updateDocument<T>(docPath, docField, data) async {
    try {
      return await fireStore.doc(docPath).set(
        {docField: data},
        SetOptions(
          merge: true,
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      throw UnimplementedError(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

when  operation done. i expect on firebase usage dasboard one read and one write operation happen but I see two read and one write  operation.Is there anyway solve this issue or is it okay?

Comment: Have a look at this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e) &  stackoveflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50887442/cloud-firestore-how-is-read-calculated)

Comment: The article is answered  my question.Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried updating the document  with  set and update and observed the reads and writes like below :

With [`set()`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#adding-documents) I got two reads and one write in the dashboard. set() with merge  instead of  updating existing documents  will create a new document copying existing fields while retaining the same doc id. That is where I got one extra read operation.

With [`update()`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#updating-documents)  it is updating the existing document and will get one read and one write operation.

The `docfield` passed as value should be a key, which means it needs to be passed with [] brackets. Take a look at the sample code.

```
Future updateDocument<T>(docPath, docField, data) async {
    try {
      return await fireStore.doc(docPath).update(
        {[docField]: data}, // ⇐ notice
      );
    } catch (e) {
      throw UnimplementedError(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: If i am not wrong.When i use update() method Firebase  doesnt count read just one write but set() count one read also if you use ...update({field: FieldValue.increment(value)}) operation count one read  and one write.